# I cannot create a Sawmill

Tags: terraria

I cannot make a sawmill and I am not on a multiplayer server.
I looked on the  page and the articles having the guide help which didn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

To go over it from the very beginning:

1. Harvest 10 wood blocks
2. Go into the crafting menu and craft a [work bench](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Work_Bench). Place it on the ground.
3. Go and collect 20 stone blocks, 4 wood and 3 torches (1 gel + 1 wood).
4. With these ingredients in your inventory, stand next to your work bench and you should be able to craft a [furnace](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Furnace), craft it and place it on the ground.
5. Next you will need to collect 24 iron ore (24 lead ore if you want to use lead bars) and you guessed it, 10 more wood blocks.
6. Go to the furnace and you will get the option to craft iron or lead bars, so craft 8 iron bars or 8 lead bars.
7. Go to your workbench and use 5 of the bars to craft an [anvil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Iron_Anvil) and place it down
8. Use 1 bar to craft 10 chains. You should now have 2 bars, 10 chains and 10 wood.
9. Go to your work bench and you should get the option to craft a [sawmill](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sawmill), craft it and place that sucker on the floor and BAM! you're finished.

The reason this is such an intricate process is that the sawmill is considered an advanced crafting station that isn't necessary in the early stages of the game.

---

**TL;DR:** You will need:

- 25 wood blocks
- 20 stone blocks
- 24 iron/lead ore
- 1 gel.

The crafting order is: workbench, furnace, anvil and sawmill.

Hope this helped!